# Converting a XML-file with data saved as vectors to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, elementtree

I have been trying to convert a nested XML-file to a dataframe in Python using Pandas and xml.etree.ElementTree.

The XML-looks like this:

```
<Hospital>
    <HospitalClass name = "St. Mungo's Hospital for Magical Maladies">
        <dataStorage id ="3" class="UnitVector">
            <UnitVector name="numHospitalized">
                <Data> 3; 5; 1; 2; 6; 9; 8  </Data>
            </UnitVector>
        </dataStorage>
        <dataStorage id ="1" class="UnitVector">
            <UnitVector name="numOperated">
                <Data> 5; 0; 12; 8; 4; 5; 7</Data>
            </UnitVector>
        </dataStorage>
        <dataStorage id = "2" class ="UnitVector">
            <UnitVector name="antibioticsUsed">
                <Data> 4.54; 5.71; nan; 7.12; 8.75; 2.99; 4.94</Data>
            </UnitVector>
        </dataStorage>
    </HospitalClass>
</Hospital>
```

My main problem is extracting the data in this format where it is seperated by a semicolon. I have looked all over stackoverflow without finding any similar posts.

Using

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse("Hospital.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root.iter():
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

You can access the informations stored as tags and attributes, but I am not sure how to access the values stored in the Data-field.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse("Hospital.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

df_cols = ["numOperated", "antibioticsUsed", "numHospilaized"]
rows = []

for node in root:
    numOperated = node.attrib.get("numOperated")
    antibioticsUsed = node.attrib.get("antibioticsUsed")
    numHospilaized = node.attrib.get("numHospilaized")

    rows.append({"numOperated": numOperated, "antibioticsUsed " : antibioticsUsed,
    "numHospilaized ": numHospilaized  })
df = pd.DataFrame(rows,colums = df_cols)
print(df)
```

Is a solution I have tried, but this only prints None and Nan as the only values. I have also tried to add the directory of the XML-tree in the code above, but I still end up with None values.

The table I ultimatly want in a pandas dataframe converted from the XML-file is:

|  | numOperated | antibioticsUsed | numHospilaized |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 4.54 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 | 5.71 | 5 |
| 3 | 12 | nan | 1 |
| 4 | 8 | 7.12 | 2 |
| 5 | 4 | 8.75 | 6 |
| 6 | 5 | 2.99 | 9 |
| 7 | 7 | 4.94 | 8 |

Do anybody know how you can solve this problem? I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is to split the text -> this converts it into a list, that Pandas can internally convert to a Series/Column.

```
data = """<Hospital>
     ...:     <HospitalClass name = "St. Mungo's Hospital for Magical Maladies">
     ...:         <dataStorage id ="3" class="UnitVector">
     ...:             <UnitVector name="numHospitalized">
     ...:                 <Data> 3; 5; 1; 2; 6; 9; 8  </Data>
     ...:             </UnitVector>
     ...:         </dataStorage>
     ...:         <dataStorage id ="1" class="UnitVector">
     ...:             <UnitVector name="numOperated">
     ...:                 <Data> 5; 0; 12; 8; 4; 5; 7</Data>
     ...:             </UnitVector>
     ...:         </dataStorage>
     ...:         <dataStorage id = "2" class ="UnitVector">
     ...:             <UnitVector name="antibioticsUsed">
     ...:                 <Data> 4.54; 5.71; nan; 7.12; 8.75; 2.99; 4.94</Data>
     ...:             </UnitVector>
     ...:         </dataStorage>
     ...:     </HospitalClass>
     ...: </Hospital>"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(data)
```

Collect data into a dictionary:

```
collection = {}
for entry in root.findall(".//UnitVector"):
    key = entry.attrib['name']
    values = entry.find(".Data").text.split(";")
    collection[key] = values
```

Create the dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(collection)
 
  numHospitalized numOperated antibioticsUsed
0               3           5            4.54
1               5           0            5.71
2               1          12             nan
3               2           8            7.12
4               6           4            8.75
5               9           5            2.99
6               8           7            4.94
```

Your data is going to be strings -> you can convert to int/float with `astype`

Comment: Thank you! I am wondering how you would convert the values to floats? I am trying to use:
            list(map(float, values))
But there is some values that are '' and nan, so it crashes.

Comment: When the data is in pandas, you can do `dp.astype(float)` do make sure though that there are no white spaces before or after the text in the columns